# Which is the better way of passing data to a Method

Tags: c#, .net, oop, parameter-passing

Let us say that we have 2 Classes `Expense1` and `Expense2`. Which class implementation is preferred over the other, or which is considered closer to being object-oriented?

I always thought that doing `Exp2.Calculate(1.5M,2)` is more readable than 
`exp1.Calculate()` and using the properties of exp1 Class as the needed values for the calculate Method.

**Expense1**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class Expense1
{
    public decimal ExpenseValue { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfItems { get; set; }
    private decimal result;

    public decimal Result
    {
        get
        {
            return this.NumberOfItems * this.ExpenseValue;
        }
    }

    public void Calculate()
    {
        this.result = this.ExpenseValue * this.NumberOfItems;
    }

    public void expense1()
    {
        this.ExpenseValue = 0;
        this.NumberOfItems = 0;
    }
}
```

**Expense2**

```
class Expense2
{
    public decimal Calculate(decimal expenseValue, int numberOfItems)
    {
        return expenseValue * numberOfItems;
    }
}
```

**Implementation of both classes**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Expense1 exp1 = new Expense1();
        exp1.NumberOfItems = 2;
        exp1.ExpenseValue = 1.5M ;
        exp1.Calculate();
        Console.WriteLine("Expense1:" + exp1.Result.ToString());

        Expense2 exp2 = new Expense2();
        string result = string.Empty;
        result = exp2.Calculate(1.5M,2).ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("Expense2:" + result);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you only need the `NumberOfItems` and `ExpenseValue` values in the `Calculate` method, then use `Expense2`. if you are using them somewhere else inside the `Expense` class, use `Expense`.\

Comment: If computing values does not have business/ logical rules, use a simple static method that does the calculation, otherwise encapsulate the logic by  exposing setter values for your properties.

Comment: If an expense is not going to change once its instantiated, pass the items and expensevalue as constructor parameters and then provide a Total() method that will return the product, this was the expense objects is immutable, and cannot get into an invalid state.

Comment: `Expense1` is good for data binding. `Expense2` is good for service calls. Both are good OOP for their respective uses.

Comment: This questions is primarily opinion-based. And, even considering one person's opinion, there's no generic answer to the question; it totally depends on the class and its methods.

Comment: @ataravati, I utterly disagree. Read the answers and you will see that they in no way fall into the category of "... will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise".

Comment: @ataravati I agree with with David as  this is not opinion based a Coder with enough experience should know which method is more maintainable over time and is considered as best practice.

Comment: @ataravati, the implications of choosing either of the above approaches can be severe to the application being developed. It is therefore important for the OP and all who perceive the above as an opinion-based decision to change their minds and look into the considerations and consequences of each approach. I am sure good answers and code snippets will aid in making this a valuable and educating post, so I will flag it for reopening.

Comment: Well, I was under the impression that the two classes provided in the question are just samples, and the question is more general. I agree that the question is not opinion-based if we're talking about this very specific scenario.

Comment: @ataravati, it is easy to assume the question is opinion based, especially by reading the title, as it matches a pattern for a number of bad questions; so I do not blame you for that.

Comment: @Ivaylo Slavov if you could help me with a better title that suits the example i can edit it all what i can think of is that or passing data to methods

Comment: @nayefharb, by the time I wrote my previous comment, the post showed the old title, but as I submitted it, the title changed - maybe the change happened at the same time as I commented. That is why I removed the comment. It is a better title now with a single issue - I edited it additionaly - avoid words as "best" - nothing is really best, there are just options, and some that work for you may not for others, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Expense2` is easier to read and understand what going on as it's evident from the call which parameters are used.

`Expense1` could have various side effects as the caller might forget to set the variables used for calculating before he calls `Calculate()`.

If you require access to the values that was used to calculate the result later, you can use something like this

```
public class Expense {
    public decimal ExpenseValue { get; private set; }
    public int NumberOfItems { get; private set; }
    public decimal Result { get; private set; }


    public decimal Calculate(decimal expenseValue, int numberOfItems) {
        ExpenseValue = expenseValue;
        NumberOfItems = numberOfItems;
        Result = ExpenseValue * NumberOfItems;

        return Result;
    }

    public Expense() {
        Calculate(0, 0);
    }
}
```

This will allow the internal state of `Expense` to stay consistent for the lifetime of the object, with the definition of how it's `Calculated`

Comment: You could also argue here that the internal state of the Expense instance should not change, with the exception being Result since we have a delayed computation, and hence ExpenseValue and NumberOfItems should be readonly. I would personally set the values in the constructor and have `Calculate()` parameterless.

Answer (score 3):

`Expense2.Calculate` is deterministic (has the same result every time its called with the same parameters) and because it has no side effects (the parameters are served to it, rather than via properties) it is thread-safe too. Lastly, it is simpler and easier to read.

`Expense1` is a classic OOP train-wreck with non-thread safe state, and no guarantee that `Result` will return the result of a thread's invocation of `Calculate`. Further, it is long-winded and complex to read and maintain.

I'd favour `Expense2` over `Expense1` every time. The only thing I'd change would be to make it static as there's no gain to having to create an instance of `Expense2` to call `Calculate`.

Comment: so in this case a  Method in a certain class should not use the properties of that class then what are properties of a certain class used for just for state checking ?

Comment: @nayefharb, I'd recommend following these simple rules: if you can avoid fields in a class, do so. If you must have a field, try to make it readonly and do not directly expose it. If you must expose it, try to only provide a `get` property. If it must change state, try to return a new instance of the class/struct with that updated field. If you must allow it to be directly changed, only then make the field mutable and supply a `get/set` property.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like Expense1 one bit. I think properties with public get/set should generally be avoided since it provides no encapsulation. It's hardly even better than public fields (although it does give some room for guard clauses etc down the road).

Worse than that, however, is the Calculate() method imo. It takes no arguments but it still changes the internal state of the object. It is not clear how. At the same time, the field it writes to, `result`, isn't being returned by the property `Result`, that property does the same calculation again (if you have to do calculations, generally prefer a method over a property).

Finally, it is not necessary to initialize primitive types to their default value in the constructor, number types always get initialized to 0.

===

Expense2 is better, it is more clear what is happening. Method takes two well-named arguments and give a reasonable result straight away.

If this method is the only use-case of the class, however, I would consider renaming it since it does not represent an expense, it represents something close to an expense calculator.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you want to do, but a rule of thumb is use properties when they are really linked to the object, and pass what use need as parameters when they are external to the object.

A simple example, consider having Person as a class, one of its properties is birthday, so in this case you should do this

```
public class Person{
     public DateTime Birthday{get;set;}
     public int GetAge(){
          //some implementation
     }
}
```

another example, think of having a Cube object, and in this Cube object you have a method Intersect with another cube, in this case you should pass the second cube as parameter and not make it a property of Cube because it is something external.

```
public class Cube{
     public Cube Intersect(Cube other){
         //Do your logic here
     }
}
```

Comment: I'd strongly argue against making the birthday mutable like that though. Birthdays don't change (as long as we're on the subject of good OOP practices ;) )

Comment: @kai Think of Person as Model loaded from database using EntityFramework, and it is a details that is outside the scope of the question :)

Comment: @Swift, while I am not trying to argue here, [kai's note](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695417/best-way-of-passing-data-to-a-method#comment51331664_31695729) is exactly the reason why business logic code should not work with entities directly. A better approach is to produce a suitable business object, that allows only updateable members for writing. This is again in the name of good OOP design. I would not use the entities specific issues to justify a design flaw